# SQL generate free slots on the fly from bookings table?

Tags: mysql, date

I know there's a lot of booking questions on php section.
Belive me when i tell you that I tried most of them, at least those which seems compatible. So let me explain.

I have this appointments table

```
 ID |    day     | start | end   | 
 ----------------------------------
  1 | 01-01-2018 | 09:00 | 10:00 | 
  2 | 01-01-2018 | 10:00 | 13:00 | 
  3 | 02-01-2018 | 12:00 | 15:00 | 
  4 | 02-01-2018 | 18:00 | 19:30 |
```

I was wondering, it possibile with sql to get empty time slots? The result should like something like:

```
    day     | start | end
 ---------------------------
 01-01-2018 | 00:00 | 09:00
 01-01-2018 | 13:00 | 23:59
 02-01-2018 | 00:00 | 12:00
 02-01-2018 | 15:00 | 18:00
 02-01-2018 | 19:30 | 23:59
```

The query should contain 2 dates: start_day + end_day

**I prepared a fiddle here**: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6dm8q8UtmDkkkjExYfMEbx/1

Comment: Just a 'heads up': on an international stage (like this one) using sample dates like '02-01' is rarely helpful, because no one knows whether you're referring to the 1st of Feb or the 2nd of Jan. Also, it's generally more efficient to store dates and times as single entities - even if that means repeating the date.

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, yeah i think that storing them togheter is better. But i cant change it. CAST(CONCAT(day, ' ', start) DATETIME) Maybe casting type may solve it? Or will it hit performance too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSSQL Version

```
WITH X AS 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Day, Start)sq, [Day], [Start], [End]
FROM (
SELECT [Day], [Start], [End]
FROM [appointments]
UNION
SELECT Day, '00:00', '00:00'
FROM [appointments]
UNION
SELECT Day, '23:59', '23:59'
FROM [appointments]
) T1
)
SELECT A.Day, A.[End] AS Start, b.[Start] AS End
FROM x A
JOIN x B
ON A.sq = B.sq -1
AND A.[Day] = B.[Day]
AND A.[End] <> b.[Start]
```

Mysql 5.7 version

```
SET @RowNumber = 0;

CREATE TABLE cte

SELECT (@RowNumber := @RowNumber+1) AS Rownumber, Day, Start, End
  FROM (
SELECT Day, Start, End
FROM booking
UNION
SELECT Day, '00:00', '00:00'
FROM booking
UNION
SELECT Day, '23:59', '23:59'
FROM booking
) T1
  ORDER BY day ASC, Start ASC

      ;

SELECT A.Day, A.End AS Start, B.Start AS End
FROM cte A
JOIN cte B
ON A.Rownumber = B.Rownumber -1
AND A.Day = B.Day
AND A.End <> B.Start
ORDER BY A.Day asc, A.End asc
```

Will add a fiddle to demonstrate
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6dm8q8UtmDkkkjExYfMEbx/2

Mysql 5.7 including days without bookings

```
SET @RowNumber = 0;

CREATE TABLE cte

SELECT (@RowNumber := @RowNumber+1) AS Rownumber, Day, Start, End
  FROM (
SELECT Day, Start, End
FROM booking
UNION
SELECT Day, '00:00', '00:00'
FROM booking
UNION
SELECT Day, '23:59', '23:59'
FROM booking
) T1
  ORDER BY day ASC, Start ASC

      ;

SELECT DAY, Start, End 
FROM(
SELECT A.Day, A.End AS Start, B.Start AS End
FROM cte A
JOIN cte B
ON A.Rownumber = B.Rownumber -1
AND A.Day = B.Day
AND A.End <> B.Start
UNION
SELECT DATE_ADD(A.Day, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Day, B.Start AS Start, A.End AS End
FROM cte A
JOIN cte B
ON A.Rownumber = B.Rownumber -1
AND A.Day <> B.Day
)Result
ORDER BY Day ASC, Start ASC
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6dm8q8UtmDkkkjExYfMEbx/3

Comment: Thanks MarkD, i have provided a fiddle in the question, you can start from there maybe ;)

Comment: it currently only returns gaps for days that have bookings, i'd need to do a little work to get the days between bookings e.g 00:00-23:59 on the 2018-01-02

Comment: Works! Thanks you a lot :D

Comment: Do you think it can be optimized? for example by providing a date_range or something else?

Comment: it now returns days with no bookings too, i'd need to do a little research to get parameters working, i've been exclusively mssql for my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution below. Assumed the logic of ID column is `identity(1,1)`, otherwise please generate `row_number()` for each column first. Syntax might not match with MySql, but you will get the logic and apply same if u like.

```
CREATE TABLE #result (
 [day] date NOT NULL,
 [start] time NOT NULL,
 [end] time NOT NULL
) 

declare @maxid int = (select max(id) from #booking), @counter int = 1, @day date
declare @tempStart time = '00:00', @currentStart time ='00:00'
declare @tempDay date = (select TOP 1 [day] from #booking)

while @counter <= @maxid
begin
   set @currentStart = (select start from #booking where id=@counter)
   set @day = (select [day] from #booking where id=@counter)

   if (@day > DATEADD(day,1,@tempDay))
   begin
      insert into #result values (DATEADD(day,1,@tempDay),'00:00', '23:00')
      set @tempDay = @day
   end

   if(@tempStart < @currentStart)
   begin
      insert into #result values (@day, @tempStart, @currentStart)
   end

   if(@counter = @maxid and @tempStart <> '23:59')
   begin
      insert into #result values (@day, (select [end] from #booking where id=@counter), '23:59')
   end

   set @tempStart = (select [end] from #booking where id=@counter)
   set @counter = @counter + 1
end

select * from #result
```

Example for SQL Server: https://rextester.com/live/VBNJ34000

Comment: Thanks for help Eray, is it compatible with MySql? I tried to paste inside DB Fiddle

Comment: Trying to find the correct syntax for mysql on your fiddle still. Try with me please, the logic is clear I suppose?

Comment: Kinda got it. I'm not very an sql expret yet :D but how to declare start and end date for the query? Otherwise wont it loop an ALL the rows? Pardon for my ignorance..

Comment: Another question. If we use another table, will it be the same for all users? What will happend if two different queries will be run, i suppose they will use the same table, wouldnt it generate some kind of conflict?

Comment: Hmm, if there is multiple users it is better to use a temp table instead of a permanent table. If permanent table is used, you will need to add TRUNCATE TABLE result at the beginning, hoping TRUNCATE is available in mysql.

Comment: it is going to loop all the rows, from the first ID to the last (max) id, as long as ID increases 1 by 1 for each row. Otherwise we need to add a temporary column by using row_number() function.

Comment: Hmm it will be a very large table, more that 2M rows. So looping on them all is not very efficient. Is there a way to prefilter a set of rows and then select MIN and MAX column ID from there?

Comment: @KeySee added an example for sql server in the answer for you to see the logic better.

Comment: Indeed works on SQL server, but this method skips dates. As you can see there is no 02.01.2018 00:00:00 in the results

Comment: @KeySee Please see my updated answer to handle this problem. Updated the link as well.

Comment: All that in 19 minutes? I'm impressed.

Comment: Cool, but yet not a complete solution. The last slot is not showing. Eg: 18:00:00 - 23:59:00 @Eray Your help is very apprecieted! You are getting pretty close too!

Comment: @KeySee Please check my updated query and link again.